# Qml Horizontal Scrollbar for a vertical listView

Tags: qt, listview

My sample application is below. 
Vertical scrollbar is working fine. But horizontal scrollbar handle is just filling the entire width, so i cant scroll using horizontal scrollbar.

I tried with Flickable , there both horizontal and vertical are working fine. Listview Inherits Flickable so it should work here also, but it is not .

```
    ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        width: 400;
        height: 300;

        ListView {
            id: list;
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            contentWidth:  parent.width * 4
            model: 20;
            clip : true
            delegate: Rectangle {
                height: 50;
                width: parent.width;
                color: (model.index %2 === 0 ? "darkgray" : "lightgray");
            }
            ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar{
                contentItem: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 6
                    implicitHeight: 100
                    radius: width / 2
                    color: "black"
                }}
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{contentItem: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 6
                    implicitHeight: 100
                    radius: width / 2
                    color: "black"
                }}

        }

    }
}
```